# Why I can't find out build folder after runing npm run build on a nextjs project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a project using Nextjs framework.

When I run the project using `npm run dev` command, My project runs properly, and it's okay.

But when I run the command `npm run build` to build a project, After that, I can't find a build folder.

Bellow is the full report which is a builder shown to me:

> λ npm run build
>
> > dastshafa-final@0.1.0 build
> > next build
>
> info  - Checking validity of types
>
> ./pages/cartProcess/index.js 13:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a
> missing dependency: 'displayNavbar'. Either include it or remove the
> dependenc y array. If 'displayNavbar' changes too often, find the
> parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in use
> Callback.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps 31:11  Warning: Do not use
> . Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-elem ent
> @next/next/no-img-element
>
> ./pages/index.js 14:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing
> dependency: 'setDisplayNavbar'. Either include it or remove the depend
> ency array. If 'setDisplayNavbar' changes too often, find the parent
> component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback.
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
>
> ./components/navbar.js 58:21  Warning: Do not use . Use Image
> from 'next/image' instead. See:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-elem ent
> @next/next/no-img-element 101:17  Warning: passHref is missing. See:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref
> @next/next/link-passhref 117:9  Warning: passHref is missing. See:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-passhref
> @next/next/link-passhref 118:11  Warning: Do not use . Use Image
> from 'next/image' instead. See:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-ele ment
> @next/next/no-img-element 118:11  Warning: img elements must have an
> alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for
> decorative imag es.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
>
> ./components/productDetail.js 72:6  Warning: React Hook useMemo has a
> missing dependency: 'productDetail'. Either include it or remove the
> dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps 106:15  Warning: Do not
> use . Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-ele ment
> @next/next/no-img-element 106:15  Warning: img elements must have an
> alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for
> decorative imag es.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
>
> ./components/productItem.js 18:7  Warning: Do not use . Use Image
> from 'next/image' instead. See:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-eleme nt
> @next/next/no-img-element
>
> ./components/products.js 21:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a
> missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the
> dependency arr ay.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
>
> ./components/sort.js 37:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing
> dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency arr
> ay.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps 41:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect
> has a missing dependency: 'filterProducts'. Either include it or
> remove the dependen cy array. If 'filterProducts' changes too often,
> find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in
> u seCallback.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
>
> info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rule s info  -
> Creating an optimized production build info  - Compiled successfully
> info  - Collecting page data info  - Generating static pages (4/4)
> info  - Finalizing page optimization
>
> Page                                       Size     First Load JS ┌ ○
> /                                      6.37 kB         144 kB ├   └
> css/b7d3c6e158495aa9.css             962 B ├   /_app
> 0 B             129 kB ├ ○ /404                                   194
> B           129 kB ├ ○ /cartProcess                           1.45 kB
> 130 kB ├   └ css/da339555cb6d6d6b.css             233 B └ λ
> /product/[...params]                   10.4 kB         148 kB
> └ css/f78802d3b8b60c2b.css             2.98 kB
>
> - First Load JS shared by all              129 kB   ├ chunks/framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js   42 kB   ├
>   chunks/main-a054bbf31fb90f6a.js        27.6 kB   ├
>   chunks/pages/_app-26dcf6f0f3b3e602.js  57.2 kB   ├
>   chunks/webpack-62757ff16512d194.js     1.81 kB   └
>   css/70cd855905d78aa0.css               24.4 kB
>
> λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or
> getServerSideProps) ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML
> (uses no initial props)

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look for a directory named `.next` which is the default the `build` command outputs to.

You can [set a custom directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/setting-a-custom-build-directory) (for example `build`) by adding it to the `distDir` key in `next.config.js`:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  distDir: "build",
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

If you're [exporting your app to static HTML](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export), the `export` command outputs to a directory named `out`.

Comment: In the build folder, there are some .json files and server and static folders. Are these a final output that I should upload to the Plesk?

Comment: @albert I'm not familiar with deploying Node.js apps to Plesk, but after running `build`, at a minimum you will need the `package.json` file to run `start`, the `node_modules` directory for runtime dependencies (I wouldn't recommend uploading the local version; there should be a way to run `npm install` on the remote Plesk server after uploading `package.json`), and the entire `.next` directory. I would check the Plesk docs to see if they have specific instructions on how to deploy Node.js apps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and adding this in my "next.config.js" solved it

```
const nextConfig = {
  distDir: "build", //this line will tell the build to create a file with this name
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```